# C programming to increase the size of a string

Tags: c

So I wrote this code but it gives me the same answer everytime. I am increasing the memory allocated to the pointer in steps of 4 and then print the value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n=0;
    char *name = "hello";
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(int i =0; i<n;i++){
        name += sizeof(int);
        printf("%d \n", (sizeof(&name)));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

can someone help me? I don't know whats wrong here. I don't need a different code, I just want to understand what's wrong with this.

Comment: You have to allocate some memory before you can increase the amount of memory you've allocated.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense.  And `sizeof` doesn't do that.

Comment: `name += sizeof(int);` What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: how about now? i added the word hello...I supposed that allocates memory too?

Comment: It allocates memory, but it allocates it statically for a string literal. You can't change the size of memory you didn't allocate dynamically in the first place. You need to use `malloc()` as others have said, and then `realloc()` to reallocate it.

Comment: so what do u suggest i do? because the name comes from a different function and it is static memory, but I need to increase the memory...

Comment: Dynamically allocate some memory using `malloc()`, and copy what you have into it. If you allocate enough memory using `malloc()` in the first place, then you won't need to do any reallocation afterwards.

Comment: @sush: That's exactly what dynamic memory means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following, error checking was left out for clarity:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
    int n=0;
    char *name = null;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        char *buffer = null;
        //allocate/reallocate the buffer. increases by 4 bytes every iteration
        buffer = (char*) realloc(name, (i+1)*4);
        name = buffer;
        printf("%d \n", (sizeof(&name)));
    }
    //release the memory used by the buffer
    free(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some explanations of what is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n=0;

        // this does not actually allocate any memory. It sets the POINTER name to point (like an arrow) to a read-only block that contains "hello"
    char *name = "hello";
        // string literals generally come in fixed read-only memory

    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(int i =0; i<n;i++){
            // this causes the pointer memory address to be incremented by sizeof(int) (typically 4)
            // after the first increment if it will point to a string "o" (incremented by 4 characters)
            // after the second increment it will point to some undefined memory behind "hello" in your virtual address space and will have undefined behaviour when accessed
        name += sizeof(int);

            // sizeof(&name) will give you the size of a char **. Pointer to a character pointer. 
            // Wich is the same size as all pointers.
            // = sizeof(void *) = 8 for 64-bit systems, 4 for 32-bit systems
        printf("%d \n", (sizeof(&name)));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the way to do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n=0;

    // allocate 10 bytes of memory and assign that memory address to name
    char *name = malloc(10);
    // the size of that memory needs to be kept in a separate variable
    size_t name_length = 10;

    // copy the desired contents into that memory
    memcpy(name, "hello", sizeof("hello"));

    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(int i =0; i<n;i++){

        // reallocate the memory into something with sizeof(int) more bytes
        void * tmp = realloc(name, name_length += sizeof(int));
        // this can fail
        if (tmp) {
            name = tmp;
        } else {
            perror("realloc");
            exit(-1);
        }

        printf("%d \n", name_length);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not allocated any memory for the pointer at all in the code you provide. You will have to deal with dynamic memory if you want to change the size of the allocated chunk. You will have to initially use [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) and then use [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) to allocate more memory on each step.

Comment: If you want things a little simpler, you could just use `realloc` each time, since you can make `realloc` act just like `malloc` by passing it a `NULL` pointer.  But that's nitpicking.

Comment: yeah...I have edited the code and given the string name the value of hello

Comment: @sush again same holds true. If you want to be able to change the size of the allocated memory, you will have to use dynamic memory and malloc/realloc as well as free.

Comment: so what do u suggest i do? because the name comes from a different function and it is static memory, but I need to increase the memory...

Comment: Do a strcpy to copy the string to a dynamically allocated one.

Answer (score 0):

Let's step through your code one by one:

```
char *name = "hello";
```

this create an array of chars `'h','e','l','l','o',0` and assignes the memory address of the first character to name

```
for(int i =0; i<n;i++){
    name += sizeof(int);
    printf("%d \n", (sizeof(&name)));
}
```

here you add to the name pointer the size of int, which increments this pointer by 4 each pass.

Since this is a char pointer, the pointer is incremented by 4 bytes - since  `sizeof(int) == 4`

You cannot increase the size of your hello char array, since it is not a dynamic array.

If you wish to be able to resize the string, you should malloc and copy the chars to the bigger array.

Comment: yes but i dont have control over the arrray. it comes from a different program and i need to add my stuff at the end of it